# jquery reference an inserted div

Tags: jquery

consider:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

The jquery says:

```
var html_to_insert = '<div id="mynewdiv"><input id="myfield" name="myfield" type="text" value="" /></div>'
$('#message').html(html_to_insert);
```

The html result is as expected:

```
<div id="message"><div id="mynewdiv"><input id="myfield" name="myfield" type="text" value="" /></div></div>
```

The problem I am having is when I call the "myfield" it does not work:

```
$('#myfield').change(function(){                      
  alert("field changed");                       
});
```

How can I fix this?

I believe the reason that it will not call it is because the field does not exist when the page first renders, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First

```
$('#myfield').change(                        
  alert("field changed");                       
);
```

is invalid. it should be:

```
$('#myfield').change(function(){                      
  alert("field changed");                       
});
```

but if you are calling it on page load you should use live.

```
$('#myfield').live('change', function(){                      
  alert("field changed");                       
});
```

Comment: when the page loads the #myfield does not exist.  It only exist when the jquery puts it into the html

Comment: @Jason then use the live example

Answer (score 0):

To see if the field exists do this:

```
alert($('#myfield').length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

can also just add the event after the elem is inserted to the DOM :

```
$('#message').html(html_to_insert, function () {
  $('#myfield').change(function(){                      
    alert("field changed");                       
  });
});
```